# Deploying a Specific Folder on GAE for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine

I have a problem with GAE during deployment. My site is in WordPress and contains a large number of files, so during deployment, I receive a warning message saying that I am exceeding the limit of 10,000 files. Since it is a WordPress site, I only deploy when I add a new plugin. So I was wondering if there is a possibility to deploy only one folder, in my case, the plugins folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, see if [this solution](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/1694) from a Google forum works for you.

---

**Updated on Feb 25** - The solution below won't work because the 10,000 file limit is for the entire App and not the number of files being deployed. See [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/quotas#Files) which says number of files per App is 10,000

---

If it doesn't, then see if the following works (**this is a proposal; I haven't tested it myself**)

1. Deploying to GAE only deploys the files which have changed since the last deployment (technically it compares the files on your local machine to the files in your staging bucket; see this [blog article](https://nocommandline.com/blog/how-to-download-your-source-code-from-google-app-engine-standard-env/) from us that explains this; look at the background section)
2. My proposal is

   a. Remove the plugin folder or the newer plugin that you're trying to deploy (this is to get your file count down to the 10,000 file limit)

   b. Do a deploy

   c. Then add back the plugin folder or the folder you removed from *'step a'* and do another deploy. The only changed files will now be the 'new' files you added back which should be less than 10,000)

**Note:** The reason why I suggest doing a deploy in step b before adding back your plugin is that as I mentioned in step 1, I believe GAE CLI is comparing your local files with the copy in the staging bucket. By default, files in the staging bucket are deleted after 15 days of no updates (this is explained in the referenced article). So, by first doing a clean deploy now, you ensure that the second deploy is going to do a comparison against files which you're now certain exist in the staging bucket since it's just a few minutes old

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, the first one I already tried ignoring include folder, but after the deploy the site doesn't work anymore (error 500), and the second one actually it analyzes only new files for example it tells me 0 new files but just after that it tells me more than 10 000 files, I think I won't bother too much and do compute engine instead, thanks anyway

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what happened with the second suggestion. If you don't mind, can you try explaining again?

Comment: In fact, as you said, it only checks modified folders. For instance, if I add a plugin composed of 5 files, it will tell me that there are 5 new files. However, at the next step, it will block and say that there are more than 10,000 files, in real I have the impression that it deploys the entire project rather than just the latest additions.

Comment: It will deploy only the 5 files (I've confirmed that multiple times). Your experience means the 10,000 file limit is for the entire project (already deployed files + files to be deployed) and not just the files to be deployed.

Comment: Confirmed. Each App can only have 10,000 files - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/quotas#Files

Answer (score 0):

Hey yes for example if you're running a Wordpress site on a google VPS, you can manage it via SSH or RDP.
You can manually setup the WordPress and transfer the plugin folder and any conf files manually

### example:
[Old Server]
C:/.../Desktop/wordpres-Backup/wp-content/plugins
[Copy to a folder on new server via ssh or RDP]

[New Server]
Before doing any changes Backup-Up/Clone the fresh install to save time in case of problems.
Copy the Plugins folder from old server to the new server then merge files.

Linux = Filezilla is good for non-root access file transfers.

If you want more help hmu on discord, only thing I could think of off top my head
.

Comment: I am not in VPS but in App engine (GAE)